# Nested ordered list inside unordered

Tags: html, css

I'm using lists for "Terms and conditions" page and in order to make the structure neater I'm using ordered lists. Problem is that I want to make the outer list unordered, and when I do that it's losing the count for the nested ordered lists. I know I can make it in many ways including manually, but I want to know if it's possible to handle this situation somehow.

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <h2>Title of section 1</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>Text 1.1
        <li>
          <li>Text 1.2
            <ol>
              <li>Text 1.2.1</li>
              <li>Text 1.2.2</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
      <ol>
        <li>Text 2.1
          <li>
            <li>Text 2.2
              <ol>
                <li>Text 2.2.1</li>
                <li>Text 2.2.2</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
      </ol>
      </li>
</ol>
```

Using CSS I'm able to show everything as it should be

https://jsfiddle.net/tutancamon/bfhkqtdg/41/

What I want is to remove the number in front of the titles because it already contains them...

Comment: You probably don't want lists, you probably want nested `<section>` (and potentially `<article>`) elements to produce the desired semantics

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned I know there are many options. Still wondering if it's possible ;)

Comment: You can use `list-style: none;` to remove the numbers.

Comment: `list-style` potentially overrides other list-style properties. Since the question was asking to remove the list-item markers in the list, `list-style-type` should be used instead, to be more specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use css property `list-style-type` like so:

```
ol.outer {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

This will however mess with the numbering. Which you can fix like so:

```css
ol {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol>li::before {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
}

ol.outer>li::before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<ol class="outer">
  <li>
    <h3>Section1</h3>
    <ol>
      <li> text1.</li>
      <li> text2 </li>
      <li> text3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>section 2</h3>
    <ol>
      <li> text</li>
      <li> text</li>
      <li>
        <strong>Some texts</strong>
        <ol>
          <li>text</li>
          <li>text</li>
          <li>text</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This will target all of the ordered list; which is exactly the issue OP wants to avoid

Comment: yeap, and even when I specify the exact ol it's not working properly.

Comment: @tutancamon actually i tested this on your own code and it works just fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/webbertakken/9qrpcykt/1/ 

This just gets you into the next issue of having to structuring your numbering

Comment: @webber Exactly my point! My fiddle' numberin is Okay. (I didn't save it last time, but should be fine now https://jsfiddle.net/tutancamon/bfhkqtdg/41/ )

Comment: @tutancamon fair enough. I updated my answer with a simplified and fixed version of what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unorderded list element `<ul>` sounds like what you need to use.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Title of section 1</h2>
    <ol>
      <li>Text 1.1
        <li>
          <li>Text 1.2
            <ol>
              <li>Text 1.2.1</li>
              <li>Text 1.2.2</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
    </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
      <ol>
        <li>Text 2.1
          <li>
            <li>Text 2.2
              <ol>
                <li>Text 2.2.1</li>
                <li>Text 2.2.2</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
      </ol>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, realizing I read the problem incorrectly. I think you need to use `counter-increment` and `counter-reset` like in this article: https://css-tricks.com/custom-list-number-styling/, then you could set the font-size to 0px or something for the outer list...